# What is the purpose of the [code-assist] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I came across the [code-assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-assist) tag just now. It's fairly old and dates back to 2012. It has no description and only 78 questions tagged questions over 6 years.

Does anyone know what this tag's original purpose was? Does anyone want to take a swing at adding a description?

Comment: I guess it's an IDE feature for assisting code writing like Intellisense?

Comment: It looks like this could or should be a synonym for [`content-assist`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-assist). There's also something actually called [CodeAssist](https://www.componentsource.com/product/infragistics-codeassist), but no question seems to be about that (and there is a general `infragistics` tag).

Comment: It's an option provided to help the developper giving him a short-hand or an in-time reminders or docs, most obvious are MS vstudio, webstorm and eclipse.